# onActivityResult can not call due to orientation change

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, android-orientation

I have two activities named

'First' and 'Second'

when I call `startActivityForResult()` method in the first activity will go to second activity and take some data and come back.

If the orientation of the second activity changed then after taking data it does not call 
`onActivityResult()` method.

It calls on create function .

What should I do so that the data taken from the second activity is saved and `onActivityResult()` method is called even if I change the orientation.

Comment: if any none have any problem in understanding the question please ask

Comment: You should save whatever value you need to in onPause() and restore it in onResume().  Orientation change is only one reason of many why you need to do this.

Comment: @Simon how to save the data which i will take from second activity

Comment: Save it to SharedPreferences (for example) in onPause(), then retrieve it in onResume().  Call setResult() and then finish() when you want to return the value to the first activity.

Comment: It should still call onActivityResult after an orientation change. You will have to show us a code example

Comment: having the same problem as the poster.

Answer (score 0):

In your app's manifest, did you remember to say that your `First` activity was the parent of your `Second` activity? Something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Second"
          android:parentActivityName=".First">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".First"/>
</activity>
```

Because if you do this then `onActivityResult()` should be called in `First` even if the screen orientation was different when you called `finish()` in `Second`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, the easiest way to overcome this problem is to write the result to `savedInstanceState`, below example is for just setting `Activity.RESULT_OK`, but its easily applicable to any parcelable/serializable object:

```
var setResult: Boolean = false

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    if (setResult) outState.putBoolean("saved_state_key", true)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    savedInstanceState?.getBoolean("saved_state_key")?.let {
        requireActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
    }
}
```

If you are using viewModels you don't need to write it to savedInstanceState, in that case simply check if `savedInstanceState` is not null in `onCreate` (which means the fragment/activity was recreated)

Answer (score -5):

When orientation is changing, application is reloading itself, that means it's restarting.

You can block orientation changing in your `AndroidManifest.xml` by adding that line into `Activity` declaration  :

```
android:orientation="portrait"
```

or if you want landscape orientation :

```
android:orientation="landscape"
```

Comment: i did not want to fix the orientation